# Tensor indices from Ramond

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

I'm working through Pierre Ramond's "Field Theory: A Modern Primer". I can't connect the steps in I.2.

Eq 2.6 (p. 7) gives a property of two linear transformations in relation to the Minkowski metric,

$$ g_{\rho\sigma} = g_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}_{\sigma} $$

which was derived from the previous statement the linear transformation's action on $x^{\mu}$ coordinates:

$$ g_{\rho\sigma}x'^{\mu}x'^{\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}_{\sigma}x^{\mu}x^{\nu} $$

Later, an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation is defined as

$$
\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} = \delta^{\mu}_{\nu} + \epsilon^{\mu}_{\nu} 
\tag {A} 
$$

and eq. 2.6 is used to conclude that

$$ 
0 = g_{\nu\rho}\epsilon^{\rho}_{\mu} + g_{\mu\rho}\epsilon^{\rho}_{\nu}
\tag {B}
$$

I'm new to working with the tensor indices. Clearly, there's been some rearrangement of the indices, and I'd like to know some of the rules that Ramond doesn't mention here.

To start, how is eq. 2.6 a valid statement by itself (without acting on $x^\mu$)? If we uses the metric tensor to contract the indices,

$$ g_{\rho\sigma} = \Lambda_{\nu\rho}\Lambda_{\mu\sigma} $$

it seems like we're left with a statement with hanging $\mu$ and $\nu$ indices.

Anyway, my main goal is to show each step from (A) to (B). Naively expanding eq. 2.6 using the definition of the LT,

$$ 
g_{\rho\sigma} = g_{\mu\nu}(\delta^{\mu}_{\rho}+\epsilon^{\mu}_{\rho})(\delta^{\nu}_{\sigma} + \epsilon^{\nu}_{\sigma}) 
$$

expanding and ignoring second-order terms as instructed,

$$
= g_{\mu\nu}(\delta^{\mu}_{\rho}\delta^{\nu}_{\sigma} + \delta^{\mu}_{\rho}\epsilon^{\nu}_{\sigma} + \delta^{\nu}_{\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu}_{\rho})
 $$

Now we get to a point were we can't blindly apply to rules anymore (unless there are some rules I don't know about). We have two elements, all with different indices. Take for example $\delta^{\mu}_{\rho}\delta^{\nu}_{\sigma}$. I view this as a way of zooming in on matrix multiplication by considering two arbitrary matrix elements. If this is the case, then the two elements would only ever meet if $\mu = \sigma$. Unfortunately, making the substitution $\sigma \rightarrow \mu$ doesn't lead to (B).

Can I have help 1) Generally understanding the rules of tensor indices, and 2) solving my specific (A) $\rightarrow$ (B) problem?

Comment: It looks like your general issue, which is responsible for all these problems, is that you don't know about tensor contraction. For example, what do you think $g_{\mu\nu} \delta^\mu_\rho$ is? If you don't know, go back earlier in the book to where contraction is introduced.

Comment: If you ever get hanging indices, you’ve done something wrong. Similarly, a term can have only two of the same index, and one must be up and one down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Some rules for indices:

- You can use $\delta_{ij}$ to contract indices. Since you know the shape of this matrix ($\delta_{ij} = 0$ if $i \neq j$, and $\delta_{ii}=1$), you know that it is only nonzero if $i = j$, therefore when you sum over repeated indices, you know the only ones that are nonzero are those such that $i = j$. For example: $g_{\mu \nu} \delta^{\mu}_{\sigma} = g_{0 \nu} \delta^{0}_{\sigma} + g_{1 \nu} \delta^{1}_{\sigma} + g_{2 \nu} \delta^{2}_{\sigma} + g_{3 \nu} \delta^{3}_{\sigma}$. Using the definition of the delta, keep only the non-zero elements and contract the indices again to get: $ g_{\mu \nu} \delta^{\mu}_{\sigma} = g_{\sigma \nu}$. You can do some googling to find a full prove of this.
- You can rename repeated indices, for example $g_{\mu \nu} \delta^{\mu}_{\sigma} = g_{\rho \nu} \delta^{\rho}_{\sigma}$.

So for your problem:
$$
g_{\sigma \rho} = \left(g_{\mu \nu} \delta^\mu_\rho \delta^\nu_\sigma \right) + \left( g_{\mu \nu} \delta^\mu_\rho \right) \epsilon^\nu_\sigma + \left( g_{\mu \nu} \delta^\nu_\sigma \right) \epsilon^\mu_\rho
$$
I ordered it in such a way that it hopefully becomes a bit clearer how to contract the indices. Try this yourself with the rules I gave above!

Then you get:
$$
g_{\sigma \rho} = g_{\sigma \rho} + g_{\rho \nu} \epsilon^\nu_\sigma + g_{\mu \sigma} \epsilon^\mu_\rho
$$

The $g_{\sigma \rho}$ cancel of course, and you can rename some *repeated* indices on the right side of the equation to get the result you gave in B.

There are many books about working with tensor indices out there. I learned working with tensors from Foster's *General Relativity*, if you are interested in GR, maybe have a look at it.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you. I looked in a lot of books before I asked this question.